# NodeJS: understanding variable scope in modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Using NodeJS v0.12.1, in the following, I am trying to read an external file into a config object, and execute some tests using the values provided by that object.

I thought that `config` would be in scope for the `before` function, but I am getting the error `ReferenceError: config is not defined` for the first line in the `before` function. Why can't `config` be accessed within `before`?

```
module.exports = {
  config                  : require('../../testconfig.json'),
  before                  : function (browser) {
    pass = config.pass;
    siteroot = config.local.address + config.local.subdir;
  },
  after                   : function (browser) {
    //we'll come up with something later....
  },
  'Testing the Login page': function (browser) {
    var greeting = 'Welcome, ' + user + '!';
    browser
        .url(siteroot)
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
        .setValue('input[id=UserNameEdit]', user)
        .setValue('input[id=PasswordEdit]', pass)
        .click('#LoginBtn')
        .pause(1000)
        .assert.containsText('#usergreeting', greeting)
  }
};
```

Comment: You defined it as a property of module.exports, it isn't in variable scope.

Comment: Simplified example: `var foo = {bar: 42, baz: function() { }};`. `bar` does not magically become a variable inside `foo.baz`. That's just how JS works and has nothing to do with Node.

Comment: You're right: I was misreading the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a scope issue.

`config` is not a variable. It is a property of the object (or will be once the object literal has finished being evaluated).

You need to access `this.config`.

Comment: Thank you: I completely blew passed the obvious. Sorry, and thanks for clarifying.